# StumpWM as window manager

Tags: compiz, window-manager

How can I set up StumpWM to be my windows manager on Ubuntu 10.10?  Right now I am using Compiz.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

StumpWM is a very minimal window manager....

> Stumpwm attempts to be customizable yet visually minimal. There are no
>   window decorations, no icons, and no buttons. It does have various
>   hooks to attach your personal customizations, and variables to tweak.

[source](http://www.nongnu.org/stumpwm/)

**To install**

With Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install stumpwm
```

Then create a sessions file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/xsessions/stumpwm.desktop
```

Paste the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=XSession
Exec=stumpwm
TryExec=stumpwm
Name=StumpWM
Comment=Stump window manager
```

[source](http://www.xsteve.at/prg/stumpwm/)

Logout and login - but choose the stump session:

[image]

<kbd>CTRL t</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd> reveals the help screen.

[image]